# WHILE result<value, argument**2

Tags: python, while-loop

New to Python and programming, following an exercise from a book.

The program should take a value and keep printing "to the power of  '+1' " on every new line, using WHILE.

My code:

```
x = 2

def powerof2_table_while(victim):
  line=1
  result=victim**(line)
  while result < 100:
""" want to write:    1.: 2 to the power of 1 is 2
               2.: 2 to the power of 2 is 4
               3.: 2 to the power of 3 is 8 """
    print (line,".:\t", victim, "to the power of\t",line,"\t is", result)
    line=line+1
    return line
  return line

resultat=powerof2_table_while(x)
print(resultat)
```

Instead of returning the table of line + victim to the power of (line) it gives back only the first line and then stops.

May I humbly ask for a help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You have multiple returns and one is inside the loop, So it will return on the first iteration. What exactly were you expecting to return? A value or a list of values? Given the function prints stuff, do you even need a return value?

Comment: you are having `return` in the `while` look which is causing your function to exit after the first iteration. Also check [Why would you use the return statement in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129285/why-would-you-use-the-return-statement-in-python)

Comment: Answering myself. Like this it works. Result must be IN the while loop. http://www.fsiforum.cz/upload/soubory/nezarazene/code__rep.png Thanks everybody anyway!

Comment: I added the returns to the code because I assumed that it doesnt get the results of the indented blocks back out of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as the unnecessary return, you also never update the result variable, you should move this inside of the while loop to avoid the infinite loop and incorrect outputs

```
result=victim**(line)
  while result < 100:
```

should be

```
result=0
while result < 100:
    result=victim**(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `return line` inside your loop. As soon as the code hits a return it, well, returns; meaning the function ends and the loop does not continue.

You don't need that return; remove it.

Comment: Hey Daniel! I saw that yo edited my post to correct formatting. May I ask for a short help with this so that my future posts dont lack this and dont disturb the other users?

Comment: @Jewenile Just select the part of code block and click the `{}` button in the editor

Comment: There's a big yellow help box right next to the space where you enter your code which tells you what to do.